# How to specify the number of columns for ListView for "single row" layout in VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, user-controls

So I created this ListView user control in VB, and specified my data source. The layout I used is "single row" layout and the paging is enabled. However, the result is exactly 10 columns (10 windows) for the row. I'm wondering how could I make the default column to be 5? I checked the properties and there seems to be no such property that controls how many columns to start with for the row.

Thanks

Edit: code for reference

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="RssDataSource1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <td runat="server" style="background-color:#DCDCDC;color: #000000;">
                title:
                <asp:Label ID="titleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("title") %>' />
                <br />
                link:
                <asp:Label ID="linkLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("link") %>' />
                <br />
                description:
                <asp:Label ID="descriptionLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("description") %>' />
                <br />
                pubDate:
                <asp:Label ID="pubDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pubDate") %>' />
                <br />
                category:
                <asp:Label ID="categoryLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("category") %>' />
                <br />
            </td>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <td runat="server" style="background-color:#FFF8DC;">
                title:
                <asp:Label ID="titleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("title") %>' />
                <br />
                link:
                <asp:Label ID="linkLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("link") %>' />
                <br />
                description:
                <asp:Label ID="descriptionLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("description") %>' />
                <br />
                pubDate:
                <asp:Label ID="pubDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pubDate") %>' />
                <br />
                category:
                <asp:Label ID="categoryLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("category") %>' />
                <br />
            </td>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <table style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        No data was returned.</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <InsertItemTemplate>
            <td runat="server" style="">
                title:
                <asp:TextBox ID="titleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("title") %>' />
                <br />
                link:
                <asp:TextBox ID="linkTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("link") %>' />
                <br />
                description:
                <asp:TextBox ID="descriptionTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("description") %>' />
                <br />
                pubDate:
                <asp:TextBox ID="pubDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pubDate") %>' />
                <br />
                category:
                <asp:TextBox ID="categoryTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("category") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" 
                    Text="Insert" />
                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
                    Text="Clear" />
            </td>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table runat="server" border="1" 
                style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                <tr ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">
                    <td ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div style="text-align: center;background-color: #CCCCCC;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #000000;">
                <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server">
                    <Fields>
                        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" 
                            ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                        <asp:NumericPagerField />
                        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowLastPageButton="True" 
                            ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                    </Fields>
                </asp:DataPager>
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <td runat="server" style="background-color:#008A8C;color: #FFFFFF;">
                title:
                <asp:TextBox ID="titleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("title") %>' />
                <br />
                link:
                <asp:TextBox ID="linkTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("link") %>' />
                <br />
                description:
                <asp:TextBox ID="descriptionTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("description") %>' />
                <br />
                pubDate:
                <asp:TextBox ID="pubDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pubDate") %>' />
                <br />
                category:
                <asp:TextBox ID="categoryTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("category") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" 
                    Text="Update" />
                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
                    Text="Cancel" />
            </td>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <SelectedItemTemplate>
            <td runat="server" 
                style="background-color:#008A8C;font-weight: bold;color: #FFFFFF;">
                title:
                <asp:Label ID="titleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("title") %>' />
                <br />
                link:
                <asp:Label ID="linkLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("link") %>' />
                <br />
                description:
                <asp:Label ID="descriptionLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("description") %>' />
                <br />
                pubDate:
                <asp:Label ID="pubDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pubDate") %>' />
                <br />
                category:
                <asp:Label ID="categoryLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("category") %>' />
                <br />
            </td>
        </SelectedItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: What do you get returned from your datasource? Is it possible that you receive 10 values? In this case, if you only want 5 columns and then a new row, you could do it in your code-behind.

Comment: Maarten, there are actually 19 records. I actually want to keep the single row, if the user wants to see beyond the first 5 record, they can press the next button (which is enabled in the ListView configuration) to slide and see the rest of the data records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the default number of records to be shown can be specified in the pager control:

asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PageSize="5"

combined with GroupItemCount property, the problem is solved. Thanks all for the help anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code? Are you trying to sort by Column 5, or display Column 5 first?

What type is the data source?

Regardless, the filtering will be in your code behind.

Try here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.columns.aspx

(You could always include all columns and hide just the ones you don't want too:
[Does anyone know of a way of hiding a column in an asp.net listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70758/does-anyone-know-of-a-way-of-hiding-a-column-in-an-asp-net-listview) )

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi rjcup3, I have added the code, as you could see, I just directly drag and dropped the "ListView" control from the toolbox. and specified the source to be "RssDataSource1" which is actually a RSS for a calender. So I would like to have only 5 windows(columns) to display the first 5 days of events. Then if the user want to look further down the date, they can press Next to see the events in the future. So yes I only what to see 5 at a time. But by default, the ListView gives me 10 columns.

Comment: If you still want the data source to display the next 5 when you click next, hiding / unhiding is probably your best. When they click next, hide the first 5, show the second set.

Comment: rjcup3, thanks for your quick response. Actually there are 19 records. It shows the first 10 records at beginning. Since I have paging enabled. when I click next (or page 2) it gives me the next 9 records. So I actually still want to use the paging, but instead of 10 records per page, I would like to have 5 at a time. The number of total records could vary since it's a RSS feed of a calendar. So I could not specify how many records to hide with hard-code...sorry for the confusion.

Comment: why not specifically setting the data source via code behind, I don't know if the source is in a DataTable or an array, but you can iterate through either.
Dim iIndex as Integer = 0

for iIndex to iIndex + 5
  ... DO STUFF
next

Comment: If it's xml (RSS) you can do the same thing with an iterator and just do your parsing in the for loop