# Hide column Header and data in ListView Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a ListView in my Asp.net application which has ItemTemplates. And data is bound to the listview. I want to give user flexibility to chose columns that they want to see in the ListView i.e. Show/Hide particular columns in the ListView. How can I achieve that? I tried

```
ListView1.FindControl("columnName").Visible = false;
```

But this only hides the column header and data in the ListView becomes out of order. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70758/does-anyone-know-of-a-way-of-hiding-a-column-in-an-asp-net-listview

Comment: Use any client side scripting language. Like jQuery or Javascript or vbscript.

Comment: How to do this using JQuery or Javascript?